# Mat Table/Mat Sort Header: How to get which column is sorted? Or how to keep table sorted when going back?

Tags: angular, mat-table

I have a Mat Table with Mat Sort Header. In this table, each row has a button, user can click on the button, go to another page(another component), and clicks on a ‘return’ button and goes back to the table.

When user goes back to the table, I need the table sorted if user did Mat Sort. I think I probably have to keep the info of which column is sorted by asc or desc so I can set the sorting back to the table.

something like:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSoruce" matSort (matSortChange)="sortChange($event)">
```

Is it possible to do this? Or is there any other way to achieve my goal? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you navigate between components, the original state will be destroyed. So in order to save the component's state, which in your case is angular material table, you need to use something like Redux or some other state management to save the state. You can then use Table's sort header APIs to restore the state.

https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview

Answer (score 0):

You only have to declare the element in the component as you can see in the next line:

`@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort`
and then you can find the active sorting column as you can see in the next line

`this.sort.active`